# Bootsrap image is not responsive when adding a height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create responsive images, as soon as I  set height to the pictures,it no longer becomes responsive.

Does anyone might anyone know how I can make the images responsive but have a set height, so they can look even

Below is my the link to my code.

https://jsfiddle.net/eldan88/DTcHh/37485/#&togetherjs=evQgLr6sQz

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/


/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.card {
  /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: .25rem;
}


/* Add some padding inside the card container */

.card-container {
  padding: 1.25rem;
}

.img-responsive {
  height: 180px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <div class="card">
      <div>
        <img src="https://aspenpeak-magazine.com/get/files/image/migration/11670_content_robert-deniro-aspen-peak-1-1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

      <div class="card-container">
        <h4><b>Rober Dinero</b></h4>
        <p>Architect &amp; Engineer</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <div class="card">
      <div>
        <img src="https://www.biography.com/.image/t_share/MTE1ODA0OTcxODYwOTg1MzU3/mark-wahlberg-9542335-1-402.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

      <div class="card-container">
        <h4><b>Mark Whalberg</b></h4>
        <p>Architect &amp; Engineer</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <div class="card">
      <div>
        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/wphire/image/upload/c_scale/freelancer_profile_pic_3" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

      <div class="card-container">
        <h4><b>Jonah Hill</b></h4>
        <p>Architect &amp; Engineer</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <div class="card">
      <div>
        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/wphire/image/upload/c_scale/freelancer_profile_pic_4" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

      <div class="card-container">
        <h4><b>Seth Rogan</b></h4>
        <p>Architect &amp; Engineer</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is what you want !

Note : This is bootstrap classes you are using and if you correctly implement your bootstrap style sheet you should be okay with just adding the correct classes on your div.

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/


/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.card {
  /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: .25rem;
}


/* Add some padding inside the card container */

.col-sm-3{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.card-container {
  padding: 1.25rem;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  height:auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <div class="card">
      <div>
        <img src="https://aspenpeak-magazine.com/get/files/image/migration/11670_content_robert-deniro-aspen-peak-1-1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

      <div class="card-container">
        <h4><b>Rober Dinero</b></h4>
        <p>Architect &amp; Engineer</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <div class="card">
      <div>
        <img src="https://www.biography.com/.image/t_share/MTE1ODA0OTcxODYwOTg1MzU3/mark-wahlberg-9542335-1-402.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

      <div class="card-container">
        <h4><b>Mark Whalberg</b></h4>
        <p>Architect &amp; Engineer</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <div class="card">
      <div>
        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/wphire/image/upload/c_scale/freelancer_profile_pic_3" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

      <div class="card-container">
        <h4><b>Jonah Hill</b></h4>
        <p>Architect &amp; Engineer</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <div class="card">
      <div>
        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/wphire/image/upload/c_scale/freelancer_profile_pic_4" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

      <div class="card-container">
        <h4><b>Seth Rogan</b></h4>
        <p>Architect &amp; Engineer</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting a fixed height, you get just that – a fixed height, it's no longer responsive. If you want an image to retain its aspect ratio you can use `object-fit: cover` on the image element. Doesn't work on IE and Edge though..